# Populate HTML card dynamically by fetching details from an overlay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make an HTML card that gets populated with the values and images that are input from an overlay.

1. I need help in getting the data from an overlay to the card
   2.Populating the data and image in the card like the below card sample.

An example of a single section would be very helpful.

```
        <!-- Overlay -->
          <div class="ibm-common-overlay ibm-overlay-alt-two" data-widget="overlay" data-type="alert" id="overlayExampleAlert">

            <form id="overlay" class="ibm-row-form" method="post" action="__REPLACE_ME__">

              <h1 class="ibm-bold">Usecase 1</h1>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">

                  <label for="uc-title">Use case title<span class="ibm-required">*</span></label></br>
                  <span>
                    <input type="text" value="" size="40" id="uc-title" name="uc-title">
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                  <label for="uc-desc">Use case description<span class="ibm-required">*</span></label></br>
                  <span>
                    <input type="text" value="" size="40" id="uc-desc" name="uc-desc">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                  <p class="ibm-form-elem-grp">
                    <label>No of scene(s)<span class="ibm-required">*</span></label></br>
                    <span>
                      <select id="scenes">
                        <option value="" selected>Select one</option>
                        <option value="A">1</option>
                        <option value="B">2</option>
                        <option value="C">3</option>
                        <option value="D">4</option>
                        <option value="E">5</option>
                        <option value="F">6</option>
                      </select>
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                  <label for="myInputField1">Usecase Image<span class="ibm-required">*</span></a></label>
                  <span>
                    <input id="myInputField1" type="file" data-widget="fileinput" data-multiple="false" />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                  <p class="ibm-btn-row"><button class="ibm-btn-pri ibm-btn-blue-50" style="float:right;" onclick="IBMCore.common.widget.overlay.hide('overlayExampleAlert',true);">Save</button> <button
                      class="ibm-btn-sec ibm-btn-transparent ibm-btn-blue-50" style="float:right" ; onclick="IBMCore.common.widget.overlay.hide('overlayExampleAlert',true);">Cancel</button></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the HTML of the overlay and of the card to your question.

Comment: added overlay HTML, card is a blank HTML anchor div which on click opens the overlays,after saving it need to populate

Comment: In the overlay HTML is no image, just the file input box to upload an image.

Comment: @matthias_h Thanks for responding .I have updated the wireframe images so that you can understand what I am looking.In the overlay and card are both different.

Comment: In your screenshot of the overlay there is next to the "Browse" button at least the name of the image file (CognosUC1.png). What is the HTML markup for that?

Comment: @matthias_h CognosUC1.png is the image which we upload on the overlay and after clicking save the card displays the image of buildings as shown in last screenshot and below it are the values that are entered on the overlay. Its like a preview of what we have input in the overlay. Hope this helps

Comment: Not really - in the screenshot of the overlay there is the name of the uploaded image. Can you get the HTML markup for that as it's not in the HTML of the overlay which you posted (use e.g. the DOM inspector for that).

Comment: @matthias_h oh ok I have added the inspect image above. Please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214837/discussion-between-suraj-prasad-and-matthias-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example the function to generate the card is bound to an additional button labeled "Get" as it's not possible to use the "Save" button which has a CMS-function bound to it that won't work outside of the CMS.

```js
$("#get").on("click", function() {
  let title = $("#uc-title").val();
  let desc = $("#uc-desc").val();
  let scene = $("#scenes option:selected").html();
  let image = $("#myInputField1").next("span").text().replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
  let card = "<div class='card'><div class='card-image'><img src='/images/" + image + "'/></div><div class='title'>" + title + "</div><div class='desc'>" + desc + "</div><div class='scene'>No of scene(s): " + scene + "</div></div>";
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", card);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h1 class="ibm-bold">Usecase 1</h1>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">

                  <label for="uc-title">Use case title<span class="ibm-required">*</span></label></br>
                  <span>
                    <input type="text" value="" size="40" id="uc-title" name="uc-title">
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                  <label for="uc-desc">Use case description<span class="ibm-required">*</span></label></br>
                  <span>
                    <input type="text" value="" size="40" id="uc-desc" name="uc-desc">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                  <p class="ibm-form-elem-grp">
                    <label>No of scene(s)<span class="ibm-required">*</span></label></br>
                    <span>
                      <select id="scenes">
                        <option value="" selected>Select one</option>
                        <option value="A">1</option>
                        <option value="B">2</option>
                        <option value="C">3</option>
                        <option value="D">4</option>
                        <option value="E">5</option>
                        <option value="F">6</option>
                      </select>
                    </span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                  <label for="myInputField1">Usecase Image<span class="ibm-required">*</span></a></label>
                  <span>
                    <input id="myInputField1" type="file" data-widget="fileinput" data-multiple="false" />
                    <span>(IMG_3861.jpg)</span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ibm-fluid">
                <div class="ibm-col-12-12">
                  <p class="ibm-btn-row"><button class="ibm-btn-pri ibm-btn-blue-50" style="float:right;" onclick="IBMCore.common.widget.overlay.hide('overlayExampleAlert',true);">Save</button> <button
                      class="ibm-btn-sec ibm-btn-transparent ibm-btn-blue-50" style="float:right" ; onclick="IBMCore.common.widget.overlay.hide('overlayExampleAlert',true);">Cancel</button></p>
                </div>
                <button id="get">
                Get
                </button>
```